# Why do some EV certificates show the full address of the organization, but others only show the state or city?

Tags: certificates

If I go to `www.comodo.com`, I can see their registered office address in the EV certificate:

```
CN = www.comodo.com
OU = COMODO EV SGC SSL
OU = COMODO EV SSL
O = Comodo Group Inc.
STREET = 1255 Broad St.
STREET = Suite 100
L = Clifton
S = NJ
PostalCode = 07013
C = US
2.5.4.15 = Private Organization
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2 = Delaware
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3 = US
SERIALNUMBER = 3830138
```

The same case with `www.digicert.com`:

```
CN = www.digicert.com
O = DigiCert, Inc.
L = Lehi
S = Utah
C = US
PostalCode = 84043
STREET = 2600 West Executive Parkway
STREET = Suite 500
SERIALNUMBER = 5299537-0142
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2 = Utah
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3 = US
2.5.4.15 = Private Organization
```

However, on `www.jetbrains.com`, the full address is not in their EV certificate:

```
CN = www.jetbrains.com
L = Praha 4
S = Praha 4
C = CZ
SERIALNUMBER = 26502275
O = JetBrains s.r.o.
2.5.4.15 = Private Organization
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3 = CZ
```

The street address is also no present in the EV certificate of `secure.powershop.com.au`:

```
CN = secure.powershop.com.au
L = Melbourne
S = Victoria
C = AU
SERIALNUMBER = 154 914 075
O = Powershop Australia Pty Limited
2.5.4.15 = Private Organization
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3 = AU
```

Under what circumstances will the full street address not be present in an EV certificate?

Comment: After the mandatory content you can decide how much extra you want to add.

Comment: Edited to reduce your post to **one** question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the CABForum, which produces the guidelines for EV certificates, the street number and postal codes are optional in the [EV certificate contents](https://cabforum.org/ev-certificate-contents/):

> 3. Address of Place of Business (EVG 9.2.7) – This field must contain the
>      address of the physical location for the Subject. City, state and
>      country information are required. Street number and postal codes are
>      optional.

Comment: Adding some info about who decidesnthese details would make the answer stronger. For example, I think the requestor can typically choose this what optional info to add.